# How to produce a result set based on the comparison of values between two fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
id  full_name   nickname
1   Jennifer    Jen
2   Jerome  
3   James   
4   Jeremiah    J
5   Geoffrey    Jeff
```

and am trying to make a roster so that if a student has a nickname, then they will only go by that nickname like so.

```
id  new_name
1   Jen
2   Jerome
3   James
4   J
5   Jeff
```

What's a query I can use on the orginal table to produce a result set that has the `new_name` as the student's nickname if they have one, and if has the `new_name` as their full name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "no nickname" means that `nickname` is NULL then you can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select id, coalesce(nickname, full_name) as new_name
from your_table
```

And if "no nickname" is represented as an empty string then:

```
select id,
       case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end
from your_table
```

And if you it could be either an empty string or a NULL:

```
select id,
       case coalesce(nickname, '') when '' then full_name else nickname end
from your_table
```

Comment: Sorry, the nick_name field is blank `''` if someone does not have a nickname, how would I go about approaching this?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: I added a couple more options that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [control flow function `IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(nickName, full_name) as new_name FROM your_table
```

here if nickname is null then full_name is returned else nickname is returned