# Is it possible to perform WHERE on a field formed using AS keyword in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have the following query (see [How to produce a result set based on the comparison of values between two fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147360/how-to-produce-a-result-set-based-on-the-comparison-of-values-between-two-fields/9147381#9147381)):

```
select id,
       case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end as new_name
from your_table
```

I'm getting a syntax error when I add the last line

```
select id,
       case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end as new_name
from your_table
where new_name = 'Jen'
```

Can I filter out the result set with a `WHERE` statement?

Comment: i think you need to wrap the first statement in a 'select * from', ie - use a subquery

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I get the error message `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'new_name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the syntax error you mentioned, so changed my connent shortly after. my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a subquery:

```
select t.id, t.new_name from
(select id,
   case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end as new_name
from your_table) t
where t.new_name = 'Jen'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've used MySQL, but try

```
select id, 
       case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end as new_name 
from your_table 
where case nickname when '' then full_name else nickname end = 'Jen'
```

Or, you could use a subquery. It occurred to me after I posted this response, and Ken White beat me to it! I checked on a local database and the execution plans are the same for both approaches, although your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use the new_name fieldname if you wap the first statement in " select * from ( ... ) "

ie - use a subquery